# Remove dependencies from package.json for React application

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am a developing a react ui, and i am having trouble eliminating some dependencies. These dependencies have security findings and I am not able to remove/eliminate from package.json. I tried npm uninstall but dosent seems to be solving the problem. The dependencies I wanted to eliminate are js-yaml, tough-cookie,http-proxy agent etc...

Please help... thanks in advance

Comment: delete your node-modules folder, delete the unwanted dependencies from package.json and then do npm install. This should fix your problems.

Comment: Are they dependencies of packages you're installing?

Comment: These dependencies are installed by create react app, so my oackage.json has only react. These are nested inside, so i am not sure how to exclude them

Comment: @adam yes they are nested dependencies

Comment: have you tried     npm remove <dependencie name> ?

Comment: which version of `react-scripts` do you have installed?

Comment: I am using react 16.6 version

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting security warnings when creating a project with Create React App, you mostly likely aren't using the most recent version of Node and/or NPM.

I just reproduced the security warning problem when I started a project on Node v8.16. When I updated Node to the most recent version (v10.15.3 at the time of writing this), I no longer got any security warnings when starting a project.

Update Node and NPM to the most recent versions.

---

Removing the individual packages that are causing the security warnings for you is not an option since NPM doesn't have a dependency exclusion feature. All dependencies are installed for each package.

Comment: I dont think that answers my question, its not about npm verisin. I have latest node version.Its those dependencies that have security vulnerabilities. Maven can do it in java very easily, using a exclusions filter. But I am not sure how npm does it

Comment: NPM doesn't have an exclusion feature. All dependencies are installed with each package.